# Share image only via Email

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made a application in which user opens the camera and captures a image.Now i want that image to be directly share via Email.For this i have used intents.But my problem is that when user finsh capturing the image multiple options comes like whatsap,google,gmail,hike etc.I only want user to share the image only via Email not with other applications

COde

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://" + fileUri.getPath());
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                        "Send mail..."));


            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: first save image in sdcard or phone store then send email

Comment: What if sir i dnt wanna save that img ,just directly share via email

Comment: thats good but directly not send image via email .ok you don't waana save image in sdcard then download image from url in Bitmap then send bitmap via email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest filtering the options that the user can use to share the file and limit it to only the email app.

Try something similar to this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
    emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, // email body);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, // email subject);
    // Add Image to email

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
    sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");


    Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, resources.getString(R.string.share_chooser_text));

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();        
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
        // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
        ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(packageName.contains("android.email")) {
            emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        } 
            intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
        }
    }

    // convert intentList to array
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray( new LabeledIntent[ intentList.size() ]);

    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    startActivity(openInChooser);
```

Comment: what about Gmail and hotmail and ... ?